# InvalidArgumentException: Database [advertiser] not configured.

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-events

I have this weird error. In our app when an user creates or updates a group, we are adding that group to our Solr search index or update existing data through events. It used to work fine but now it has started to throw this error.

**database.php**

```
'connections' => [

        'mongodb' => [
            'driver'   => 'mongodb',
            'host'     => env('MONGO_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port'     => env('MONGO_DB_PORT', 27017),
            'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('MONGO_DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD'),
            'options' => [
                'db' => 'admin', // sets the authentication database required by mongo 3
            ]
        ],

        'advertiser' => [
            'driver'   => 'mysql',
            'host'     => env('ADVERTISER_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port'     => env('ADVERTISER_DB_PORT', 3306),
            'database' => env('ADVERTISER_DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('ADVERTISER_DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('ADVERTISER_DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

    ],
```

The listener method in `GroupEventSubscriber.php`

```
public function onNewGroupCreate(\App\Events\NewGroupCreate $event)
    {
        $group = $event->group;
        // this method adds the group to our solr index
        // i've commented out the method call after it started to throw error, but it still being called. 
        // the onGroupUpdate() method is similar to this
        //$this->addGroupToIndex($group);
    }
```

Now every time I create or update a group this is the stacktrace i get. Note: I have commented out the `addGroupToIndex()` method call in both `onGroupUpdate()` and `onNewGroupCreate()

InvalidArgumentException: Database [advertiser] not configured.
in /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php:239

> Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php(158):
>
> Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->getConfig('advertiser')
>
> ## 1 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php(68):
>
> Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->makeConnection('advertiser')
>
> ## 2 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(3351):
>
> Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->connection('advertiser')
>
> ## 3 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(3317):
>
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection('advertiser')
>
> ## 4 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1861):
>
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getConnection()
>
> ## 5 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1834):
>
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newBaseQueryBuilder()
>
> ## 6 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1804):
>
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQueryWithoutScopes()
>
> ## 7 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(726):
>
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQuery()
>
> ## 8 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Eloquent/HybridRelations.php(26):
>
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->hasOne('App\Advertiser', 'id',
> 'place_id')
>
> ## 9 /var/www/tagfi/api/app/Group.php(67): App\Group->hasOne('App\Advertiser', 'id', 'place_id')
>
> ## 10 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(2706):
>
> App\Group->advertiser()
>
> ## 11 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(2679):
>
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getRelationshipFromMethod('advertiser')
>
> ## 12 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(2623):
>
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getRelationValue('advertiser')
>
> ## 13 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(3466):
>
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getAttribute('advertiser')
>
> ## 14 /var/www/tagfi/api/app/Listeners/GroupEventSubscriber.php(50): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__get('advertiser')
>
> ## 15 /var/www/tagfi/api/app/Listeners/GroupEventSubscriber.php(90): App\Listeners\GroupEventSubscriber->addGroupToIndex(Object(App\Group))
>
> ## 16 [internal function]: App\Listeners\GroupEventSubscriber->onGroupUpdate(Object(App\Events\GroupUpdate))
>
> ## 17 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/CallQueuedHandler.php(42):
>
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> ## 18 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(73):
>
> Illuminate\Events\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob),
> Array)
>
> ## 19 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(203):
>
> Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
>
> ## 20 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(152):
>
> Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('redis',
> Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob),
> Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
>
> ## 21 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(75):
>
> Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runNextJob('redis', 'default',
> Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
>
> ## 22 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(100):
>
> Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('redis', 'default',
> Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
>
> ## 23 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(83):
>
> Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('redis', 'default')
>
> ## 24 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->fire()
>
> ## 25 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(508):
>
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> ## 26 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(169):
>
> Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
>
> ## 27 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(261):
>
> Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 28 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(155):
>
> Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 29 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(817): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 30 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(185): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand),
>
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 31 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(116): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 32 /var/www/tagfi/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(121):
>
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 33 /var/www/tagfi/api/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>
> ## 34 {main}

i know this is too long, but I can't seem to find whats causing the issue.

Comment: did you try stopping the queue executor? and flushing all the jobs?

Comment: I've run `php artisan queue:restart`. and we are using redis for queue so flushed the keys too

Comment: are you using any caching technique? that caches the code? like `go aop framework`

Comment: nothing like that. I also used `Cache::flush()`

Comment: Dumb question: did you flush the `config` cache with `php artisan cache:clear`? just to be sure

Comment: yes i did. Still the same issue